# Best C# collection for hierarchical data storage

Tags: c#, collections, containers, bigdata, hierarchical-data

My data has hierarchical relation. Lets imagine a human chromosomes. We have 24 chromosomes, each is double stranded (i.e., +/-) and on each strand we have multiple regions. Lets suppose regions on different strands and chromosomes are independent. Currently I store all regions as following:

```
List<List<List<Region>>> regions;
```

First list denotes chromosomes, second list strands, and third list represents regions.

For my processing purposes, various insertion/deletion to these list plus lots of sequential and random accesses are needed. And since there could be a huge number of regions (billions) efficiency in terms of speed and memory consumption is critical. Number of chromosomes for human are 24 and only 2 strands hence : [24 x 2 x 1E+9] is a possible size of `regions`.

`regions` is the base, hence I was wondering if there is any better solution for my data in-memory representation.

Comment: Why not create an object hierarchy where one encapsulates the other?

Comment: could you please clarify your suggestion ?

Comment: Have a look at [Wintellect.Powercollections](http://powercollections.codeplex.com/). BigList seems to be very suitable for you

Comment: In which universe do humans have 24 chromosomes?

Comment: If you want `Chromosome`, `Strand`, `Region`: Why do you come up with `List<List<List<Region>>>`. This does not look like a very good model.

Comment: @Default: Not an extra, but an extra copy of no 21 for a total of 47. It's not relevant to the question, just sloppy.

Comment: @David: 23 chromosome in nucleus and one mitochondria chrM

Comment: @Mare: Absolutely agree, but unfortunately list of list was the only practical+simple solution I found.

Comment: @Hamed Solution to what? This has at least cubic complexity in terms of time, so it will be one of the slowest ways to get the data you need.

Comment: @Hamed: Mitochondrial DNA is not organised as chromosomes and is not paired. But: a male has 24 different chromosomes, 23 of them paired plus X + Y. Best if you pick a data structure where this doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to create a custom object to hold a hierarchical data. For example:

```
public class Region
{
    public List<Region> Regions { get; set; } 
    ... other properties, methods, etc
}
```

And as I see you will need some heavy calculations using this data. So you probably will try to make this calculations async, if so take a look at [System.Collections.Concurrent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace for multithreading collections.

Comment: The model is like the one Mare mentioned ... still I don't see the difference between a List of Lists and this model. Thank you for suggesting Concurrent collections, I think I should have my model first ;-)

Answer (score 1):

From your example can be deduced that the smallest unit that you need is a `base-pair`.

So, I would model it something like

```
public class Genome
{
    public List<Chromosome> Chromosomes {get;set;} // has 23 elements on average
}

public class Chromosome
{
    public List<Region> Regions {get;set;}
}

public class Region
{
    public List<BasePair> BasePairs {get;set;}
}

public class BasePair
{ 
   // some combinations of proteins
}
```

Depending on how performant you need your data, I would back that up with a database.

Databases have generally no problems with storing 3 billion datasets (the suggested size here),
and you could distribute your database across multiple computers to enhance computation speed.

And, which is most important: Databases are optimized for random, sequential access to very large datasets. Database technology is one of the most mature technologies in computer science.

Comment: Well your model to me seems nothing but a list of lists. Your Genome is list of Chromosomes where each chromosome is yet another list of Regions ... So I don't see why this model will perform better than List of lists.

Comment: Regarding databases, agree, our data are in TB and are all stored on databases with a cluster processing it in a distributed fashion. But the problem is the type of queries you need, which leaves no option but loading essential data all in memory in such a data structure to run the query.

Comment: There were times when it was not possible to load gigabytes into memory and still there where ways to search in a gigabyte sized textfile. Perhaps this is your way to go. Perhaps you can provide more information on how your query requirements are formed, the datastructures can be modelled towards any known requirement.

Comment: Let me clarify. In practice, I have `List<List<IndexedStrand>>`. IndexedStrand class indexes all millions of regions on chrN-strandM in a compressed way. In few milliseconds in runs queries such as "Find regions with most condensed ChIP-seq peaks around". IndexedStrand suits best for our needs but the problem is we are looking for better substitution for `List<List<IndexedStrand>>`.

Comment: Bring in the information you have in your model. A List of Lists has very little information about what is expressed. If you see that there are some queries for signals that you need, move your model in that direction. Think about distribution of that data and about in-memory databases on large clusters. They will perform best for your needs I think. With an expressive Model, optimization can go for Regions now, not for List<List>.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Let me ask a point, lets suppose your `Chromosomes` has 3 elements; when adding one `Region` to `Regions` of 2nd `Chromosome`, do all `Regions` of 3rd `Chromosome` will be shifted  ?

Comment: I do not understand. What shall be shifted? I think of it like each chromosome is stored on a separate computer. Think nothing will be shifted on another computer then. If you need more performance, shard your regions on more computers.